# Toggle Bootstrap Column Properties inside a DIV Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, toggle

I've been kicking myself trying to swap Bootstrap class properties inside a div tag.  I want to take full advantage to Bootstrap 12 column grid, but toggle 12 columns into one 9 columns and 3 columns layout. Here's the example:

Here's the [**JDFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/044c1973/6/).  This the sample code:

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div id="LeftColumn" class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Left Column</h3>
    <p>Currently is set to col-md-9, but it should initially be col-md-12 and be toggled to col-md-9 while maintining the its responsive properties.</p>
    <p><span class="strong">DESIRED RESULT:</span>Toggle the properties &lt;div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"&gt; to &lt;div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"&gt; when the "Toggle Right" column button is clicked while maintaining the existing functionality.</p>
    </p>
    <div id="Bar" class="main-container collapse in">
      <a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse">Toggle Right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="RightColumn" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <div id="Foo" class="main-container collapse" style="border: dotted 1px green;">
  Toggle Left Column <a href="#Bar" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>Additional content will be displayed in this column once triggered.
      <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to maintain the toggle functionality already in place in the existing buttons "Toggle Right" and "Toggle Left" buttons.

I would immensely appreciate some help getting to the classes in both RightColumn and LeftColumn to toggle from 12 (col-md-12) to 9 (col-md-9) and 3 (col-md-3), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Js/Jquery to do that. I have update your code for toggle right button assuming initially your left column was set to col-md-12. Onclick of toggle button you can add or remove classes on whatever you like.  Updated code is now as below.
`

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 border-red">
<div class="col-lg-12 align-center"><h3>Sample Table</h3></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 border-black align-center">
  Right Column Full 12 Columns (col-md-12) before triggering Toggle button.
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 border-green">Main Container (col-md-9) after toggle button is clicked should still maintain its responsiveness properties.<br /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 border-blue">Toggle Right Column<br />(col-md-3)</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div id="LeftColumn" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3>Left Column</h3>
        <p>Currently is set to col-md-9, but it should initially be col-md-12 and be toggled to col-md-9 while maintining the its responsive properties.</p>
        <p><span class="strong">DESIRED RESULT:</span>Toggle the properties &lt;div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"&gt; to &lt;div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"&gt; when the "Toggle Right" column button is clicked while maintaining the existing functionality.</p>

        <div id="Bar" class="main-container collapse in">
          <a href="#Foo" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" id ="toggle-right">Toggle Right</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div id="RightColumn" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div id="Foo" class="main-container collapse" style="border: dotted 1px green;">
      Toggle Left Column <a href="#Bar" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>Additional content will be displayed in this column once triggered.
          <div style="height: 150px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`
```

Updates js code is below

```
    $(".main-container.collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  //when a collapsed div is shown hide all other collapsible divs that are visible
  $(".main-container.collapse").not($(this)).collapse('hide');
});
$('#toggle-right').click(function(e) {
var left = $('#LeftColumn');
if(left.hasClass('col-md-9'))
{
left.removeClass("col-md-9 col-sm-9").addClass("col-sm-12 col-md-12");
}
else
{
left.removeClass("col-md-12 col-sm-12").addClass("col-sm-9 col-md-9");
}
})
```

Your updated JsFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/044c1973/8/).  Now based on this you can add your left toggle button also.

Comment: Almost!  I appreciate your help. The result is almost to the ideal, except that the when you click the orange button, the Left Column should re-assume the 12 columns again, just like the initial state.

Comment: So, Left Column starts with 12 columns until "Toggle Right" button is clicked to display the Right Column at 3 columns while Left Column would then shrink to 9 columns. Once the orange button is clicked, then Right Column retracts and Left Column now assumes the value of 12 columns.

I was playing around with the columns, but I don't know if It was the right change. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to toggle between a specific div being `class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"` and `class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"` by clicking on a button?

To do this you can use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$("#button-id").click(function(){
  if ($("#div-to-change").hasClass("col-md-12")) {
    $("#div-to-change").removeClass("col-md-12 col-sm-12").addClass("col-md-9 col-sm-9");
  } else {
    $("#div-to-change").removeClass("col-md-9 col-sm-9").addClass("col-md-12 col-sm-12");
  }
});
```

Comment: The toggle functionality is to the columns with the LeftColumn starting at 12column, and as you click green button LeftColumn has its value change from 12 to 9 and the RightColumn is displayed with a value of 3 columns.  As you click the orange button, the RightColumn is hidden and the RightColumn goes back to assume the 12 columns value.  A swap from 12 columns to 9 and 3, and back to 12 columns.